# docker certificate error when building for arm/v7 platform

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate

I have this basic dockerfile which download `wget` et use it.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    wget libssl-dev ca-certificates \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    
RUN wget -nv https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.75.0/source/boost_1_75_0.tar.bz2
```

When I try to build it for the platform `linux/arm.v7` I get the following error during the `wget`

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7 -f test.dockerfile -t image_test folder/
```

```
ERROR: cannot verify boostorg.jfrog.io's certificate, issued by 'CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':                                    
    Self-signed certificate encountered.                                                                                                                                
To connect to boostorg.jfrog.io insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

But if I try to build for another platform, no error.

Those two commands succeed

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -f test.dockerfile -t image_test folder/

dockerbuild -f test.dockerfile -t image_test folder/
```

The problem happens with any link (even google.com).

Why is docker unable to verify certificates on armv7 ?

Docker version : `Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57`
Docker buildx version : `github.com/docker/buildx v0.7.1-docker 05846896d149da05f3d6fd1e7770da187b52a247`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
RUN for i in /etc/ssl/certs/*.pem; do HASH=$(openssl x509 -hash -noout -in $i); ln -s $(basename $i) /etc/ssl/certs/$HASH.0; done
```

before using wget.

I don't know what is the problem with certificates update but apparently this could be a workaround. Found the workaround [here](https://hup.hu/comment/2648030#comment-2648030)

Comment: It does work ! I'd like to have a better explanation, but this will be the fix for now